# ASCII to charecter conversion in objective c not correct for extended ascii

Tags: objective-c, ascii, converters

I have tried to implement an ascii to character converter.
code is

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",ascii]
```

It works fine for ascii upto 127
After 127 it shows the character for apple special characters

from [here](http://www.ascii-code.com/) I found that

> There are several different variations of the 8-bit ASCII table.

I need the

> ISO 8859-1, also called ISO Latin-1

Ascii while converting. How can I convert ascii to ISO 8859-1 other than APPLE's special caracters.

Answer (score 3):

```
[NSString stringWithCString:asciiString encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

where `asciiString` is your `ascii` char followed by a null byte.

Comment: Thanks for the advice,
I think you didn't understand my problem.
I can't take the ascii chrecter from ascii number.
How can I get ASCII charecter of an ascii number.
I know just assign integer to charecter but its getting apple's special character for asciinumber greater than 127

Comment: If you want something more specific, you'll need to add detail and context to your question. Why won't this solution suffice? Why do you need the character (ie. your intention of use for the character)? How are you displaying the character?

Answer (score 0):

I have entered the character encoding problem and I made encoding library. This library doesn't support ISO Latin-1 but I think you can use it with "NSISOLatin1StringEncoding".

The internal code is below:

```
+ (NSString *)encodedStringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    // Get the web page HTML
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    // response
    int enc_arr[] = {
        NSUTF8StringEncoding,           // UTF-8
        NSShiftJISStringEncoding,       // Shift_JIS
        NSJapaneseEUCStringEncoding,    // EUC-JP
        NSISO2022JPStringEncoding,      // JIS
        NSUnicodeStringEncoding,        // Unicode
        NSASCIIStringEncoding           // ASCII
    };
    NSString *data_str = nil;
    int max = sizeof(enc_arr) / sizeof(enc_arr[0]);
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        data_str = [
                    [NSString alloc]
                    initWithData : data
                    encoding : enc_arr[i]
                    ];
        if (data_str!=nil) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return data_str;    
}
```

You can download this library from https://github.com/weed/p120801_CharacterEncodingLibrary

I wish my advice be help you.

Comment: The returned data_str will only ever be encoded with NSUTF8StringEncoding. Perhaps you meant to use NSMutableString and to get rid of the break.